# text over transparent background while hovering

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get text to appear inside a table cell while hovering it. I want the text to remain hidden until I hover over it. I did that, but don't know how to make the text appear a solid color (when I hover over a cell, it decreases its opacity). Is there any way to add text on top of everything using jQuery? I would like to do so for each of the six cells. I tried using z-index to do this, but it did not work.

HTML

```
<div>
    <a NAME="work">
    <div class="samples">
    <table>
        <th>Pokemon</th>
        <tr>        
            <td id = "squirtle">
                <img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png">
            </td>
            <td><img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//006.png"></td>
            <td><img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//001.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src = "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/a/a5/Pikachu_digital_art_pokemon_by_dark_omni-d5wotdb.png/revision/latest?cb=20141113035440"></td>
            <td><img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5f/Pok%C3%A9mon_Lugia_art.png"></td>
            <td><img src = "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/f/ff/Togepi.png/revision/latest?cb=20100731212849"</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.samples table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.samples td img{
    height:300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: center;
    z-index:3;
}
.samples td{
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,300);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-color: 2px solid black;
}

.samples td#squirtle:hover p{
    visibility: visible;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.samples td:hover{
    opacity: .7;
}

.samples td#squirtle p{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".samples td img").click(function(){
    $(this).text("squirtle rules");
})
```

Comment: imgs don't have text content... you'd need to target the parent td containing the image, not the image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the text appear solid, change

```
.samples td:hover{
    opacity: .7;
}
```

to

```
.samples td:hover img{
    opacity: .7;
}
```

this will apply the opacity change to the `img`, but not everything else in the `td`.

To get the text on top of the image, first add `position: relative;` to `.samples td`, then add this rule:

```
.samples p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

`position: relative` on any element means that any of it's children with `position: absolute` will be positioned inside this parent, not the entire window.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/x1jxpe3m/

Comment: That is very helpful. However, I'm still confused about position:absolute. Why does .samples p have this property and not .samples td img ?

Comment: When you give something an absolute position, it takes it out of the normal flow of content. You wanted to take the text out of the normal flow to position it over the top of the images, not the other way around. Perhaps reading up more about positioning would help - [this guide](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) looks like it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

this was made possible without jquery

```
<div>
<a NAME="work">
<div class="samples">
<table>
    <th>Pokemon</th>
    <tr>        
        <td id = "squirtle">
            <a href="#" class="wrapper">
                <span class="text">
                    This is text
                </span>
                <img src="http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="wrapper">
                <span class="text">
                    This is text
                </span>
                <img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//006.png">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.td{
    background-color: purple;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
}
.wrapper img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color:#f00;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

img {
    z-index:1;
}


</style>
```

but if you still insist you want to do this with juery check this blog http://alijafarian.com/jquery-image-hover-captions/ and see the [Demo here](http://alijafarian.com/demos/jquery-image-hover-captions/). Good luck